# Convert react application to uml diagram

Tags: reactjs, react-native, class-diagram

is there a tool that **automatically** generates the class diagram from the code of an application developed with react?
I tried a lot of things but I did not find what I want (like `d3.js`, `projecttreeview`, `react-sight` but it gives the visualization in tree structure, and like `plantuml` I have to add code, my problem is that I do not have time),
can someone help me please, i'm really pressed for time.